# Document to Text converter, return structure of the text

Tags: converters, apache-tika

I would need a general format converter that returns the plain text and the structure of it from different document formats (doc, docx, .xls, .xlsx, pdf, etc. preferably with a JAVA API).

I currently use Tika, which introduces some errors and mainly doesn't return a structure of the text. Is there any tool which return the structure of the text attached with the converted plain text?

Comment: Tika in HTML mode, then throw away the markup once you've got whatever structure you need?

Comment: Actually, the split of the markups isn't correct, that is my problem

Comment: That's rather vague... Without any more details I'm not sure we'll be able to help!